# Why am I getting ClassNotFoundExpection when I have properly imported said class and am looking at it in its directory?

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, java-3d

This is my Javac compiling statement:

> javac -cp
>   "C:\java\code\j3D\j3dcore.jar;C:\java\code\j3D\j3dutils.jar;C:\java\code\j3D\vecmath.jar"
>   Simple.java

- compiles with no problems.

The three jar files (`j3dcore`, `j3dutils`, and `vecmath`) are the essential jar's for my program (or at least I am led to believe according to [this official tutorial on J3D](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/java3d/j3d_tutorial_ch1.pdf)

For the record I ripped this code almost line from line from the above pdf file.

- jar files are correctly located in referenced locations

When I run my `Simple` program, (`java Simple`) I am greeted with

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/media/j3d/Cavas3d Caused by: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundExpection:
>   javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D**

Currently I am staring directly at this `Canvas3D.class` that is located within `j3dcore.jar\javax\media\j3d\`

wtfisthis.jpg

Here is the source code:

```
//First java3D Program
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.applet.MainFrame;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube;
import javax.media.j3d.*;
import javax.vecmath.*;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;

public class Simple extends Applet {
    public Simple() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
        Canvas3D canvas3D = new Canvas3D(config);
        add("Center", canvas3D);

        BranchGroup scene = createSceneGraph();
        scene.compile();

        // SimpleUniverse is a Convenience Utility class
        SimpleUniverse simpleU = new SimpleUniverse(canvas3D);

        // This moves the ViewPlatform back a bit so the
        // objects in the scene can be viewed.
        simpleU.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();

        simpleU.addBranchGraph(scene);
    }   // end of HelloJava3Da (constructor)
    public BranchGroup createSceneGraph() {
        // Create the root of the branch graph
        BranchGroup objRoot = new BranchGroup();

        // Create a simple shape leaf node, add it to the scene graph.
        // ColorCube is a Convenience Utility class
        objRoot.addChild(new ColorCube(0.4));

        return objRoot;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Simple world = new Simple();
    }
}
```

1. Did I import correctly?
2. Did I incorrectly reference my jar files in my Javac statement?
3. If I clearly see `Canvas3D` within its correct directory why cant java find it?
4. The first folder in both `j3dcore.jar` and `vecmath.jar` is "javax". Is the compiler getting confused?
5. If the compiler is getting confused how do I specify where to find that exact class when referencing it
   within my source code?

Comment: can you put your java.exe commandline in the post?  i wonder if you have your classpath defined there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
java -cp "C:\java\code\j3D\j3dcore.jar;C:\java\code\j3D\j3dutils.jar;C:\java\code\j3D\vecmath.jar"  Simple
```

you need to include the classpath on the `java`commandline as well.

Comment: Thanks for such a fast response. I attempted your solution. I now get the same ClassNotFoundExpection but now its for the Simple class itself!

Comment: You need to also include the directory which contains Simple.class on the classpath. (Assuming it's not in a package, if it is, then the root of the package needs to be on the classpath instead)

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I attempted your solution, I appended ;C:\java\code\j3d to the end of the classpath. I now get a new exception, I get a

 "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no j3dcore-ogl in java.library.path

I think my problem is now outside the scope of my inital question. I belive jeremy and afk solved my initial problem. Thank you.

 If anyone can tell me whats up with this new exception that would be cool.

Comment: @Strider, I think you need to add `-Djava.library.path=/path/to/j3dcore-ogl.dll` (or whatever the file is called) to the command.

Comment: @Strider, Sounds like you need to get the correct DLL! x86-64 or x64 or amd64, whatever it's called on the download page or your preferred package manager. ;-)

Comment: @JeremyHeiler  Yes I found the correct 64 bit DLL! Thanks, this is now my JAVA command: `java -Djava.library.path=C:\java\code\J3D\ -cp "C:\java\code\J3D\j3dcore.jar;C:\java\code\J3D\j3dutils.jar;C:\java\code\J3D\vecmath.jar;C:\java\code\j3d" Simple` . When I run the command JAVAC just hangs and does nothing. I think this is a lost cause.. I dont even know why I am trying to use JAVA 3D, it is so outdated. My goal is to learn 3D programming in java. Can you suggest a different way I can learn to program 3D graphics without java 3d?

Answer (score 1):

Just doing `java simple` wont help. You need to put all those jars in classpath while you run the program. Just like you did to compile it.

java -cp `C:\java\code\j3D\j3dcore.jar;C:\java\code\j3D\j3dutils.jar;C:\java\code\j3D\vecmath.jar Simple`

Please Check [Setting the class path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)