# Java 3D error not going away

Tags: java, windows, jar

I'm currently running Windows 7

I am trying to run a .jar file that uses Java 3D. When I click the .jar file, I obtain "A java error has occurred". When I run the file from the command prompt, I obtain the following exception:

```
C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\CdsFull\Cds>java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -jar CdsViz.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/j3d/Canva
s3D
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

To fix this error I have tried installing all of the current Java components (SDK, JRE etc). I installed Java 3d version 1.5.1 using the installer AND editing the environmental variables in windows.

My user CLASSPATH variable has the following in it:

```
.;C:\PROGRA~2\JMF21~1.1E\lib\sound.jar;C:\PROGRA~2\JMF21~1.1E\lib\jmf.jar;C:\PROGRA~2\JMF21~1.1E\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java3D\1.5.1\lib\ext\j3dcore.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java3D\1.5.1\lib\ext\j3dutils.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java3D\1.5.1\lib\ext\vecmath.jar
```

My system PATH variable has the following in it:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2011a Student\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java3D\1.5.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin;
```

As you can see, the appropriate classes are in the correct variables (As far as I can tell). The issue with the program is the canvas3D class which is in j3Dcore.jar...

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I should do to get this working?

Thanks y'all.

Comment: Will this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827452/why-am-i-getting-classnotfoundexpection-when-i-have-properly-imported-said-class ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution -- 
For windows, I had to move the j3d folder from "program files(x86)" to the "program files" folder. This worked.